# From QGIS to PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I want to download my data from QGIS to an existing table in Postgresql. I tried to use DB Manager, but the field *add to existing table* doesn't work. Maybe somebody knows what the problem is?

Or is there another way to solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: User interface fools and it has never been possible according to this ticket http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10569. It is a duplicate as @Joseph writes but the old answer should be edited to show the corresponding QGIS ticket to follow.

Comment: I want to import them from tab MapInfo file. is there any way?

Comment: Thanks @user30184, a comment has been added to the old answer regarding the ticket you mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried using the SPIT plugin (Shapefile to PostGIS Import Tool)?

Comment: I have to import only from MapInfo file, I can't use Shapefiles, that's why I have a problam.

Comment: Use ogr2ogr then.

Comment: @bable - use ogr2ogr.  Along the lines of: ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=<user> dbname=postgis password=<password> active_schema=OS_Data" "\\<server>\<share>\MyTable.tab" -a_srs "epsg:27700" -nlt GEOMETRY